# Elements in relative homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to show explicitly that $A$ is isomorphic to $H_n(B^n,S^{n-1},A)$ by the map $a\mapsto [a\cdot f]$. Where $f$ is a homeomorphism from $\Delta^n\rightarrow B^n$ that restricts to a homeomorphism from $\partial\Delta^n \rightarrow S^{n-1}$.

I am getting confused with how to work with elements in $H_n(B^n,S^{n-1},A)$.

From what I understand $H_n(B^n,S^{n-1},A)=H_n(C(B^n,S^{n-1},A))$ where $C(B^n,S^{n-1},A)=C(B^n,A)/C(S^{n-1},A)$. 
This gives that $[g]\in H_n(B^n,S^{n-1},A)$
is $g+Ker(\delta_n:C(B^n,S^{n-1},A)\rightarrow C(B^n,S^{n-1},A))$. But I do not see how to work with this

Comment: Basically, this is really difficult to do. For starters you need a bunch of theorems about simplicial homology to prove that the identity map on the boundary of $\Delta^n$ actually has the properties you want.

Comment: Could you help guide me, I'm not even fully sure if my idea for an arbitrary element in $H_n(B^n,S^{n-1};A)$ is correct?

Comment: Do you need to know that the specific map that you have defined is an isomorphism or do you just need to know that H$_n(B^n, S^{n−1},A) = A$? There are much easier ways to show that they are isomorphic.

Comment: I want to know that the specific map is an isomorphism